# Doxygen: markdown links to header files are broken in html output

Tags: markdown, doxygen

Most of the links in my markdown files are correctly rendered by Doxygen (version 1.8.14 on Fedora 28), for example:

```
[utils](src/thing/utils/README.md)
```

Even though the path to Doxygen's html version of the readme is cryptic, Doxygen resolves it and the link works. But when I link to a header file, Doxygen generates a weird relative path that goes nowhere:

```
[Widget.hpp](src/thing/utils/Widget.hpp)
```

On github this link works, but the path in the html generated by Doxygen is:

```
../../src/thing/utils/Widget.hpp
```

What I would like is for Doxygen to resolve this link to the html doc page that it generated for `Widget.hpp`. Is there a way to do this, and also maintain compatibility with github? Fine with me if it requires the Doxygen preprocessor or even my own preprocessing script (to run prior to Doxygen and change the link in a temporary copy of the `README.md` to something that Doxygen understands).

Comment: In case anyone might find it useful, this command will recover the original header filenames from the Doxygen html file tree: `find doc/doxygen/html -name "*8hpp\.html" | sed -e "s/^.*\/\(_\?[^/]\+\)\.html$/\1/" -e "s/_8hpp/.hpp/" -e "s/_\([a-z]\)/\U\1/g"`

Comment: Just as a reference to people reaching this question: `[Widget.hpp](@ref Widget.hpp)` will work for Doxygen (but probably won't for GitHub).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a difficult situation.

The file README.md is translated by doxygen and the result is used. The widget.hpp is also translated but as it is unclear what to link i.e. the source code or the documentation a reference is given to the original file but in the result tree and this file is regarded as a file that can be found in the HTML tree at that position.

So best you can do is create the path in the HTML directory and copy the file to that place.

Also it would be good to create an issue in the doxygen issue tacker (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new) with attached a, small, self contained example (source+config file in a tar or zip; no references to external sources please) that allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: ok, great. Can I create a soft link (like `ln -s`) for the path within the HTML directory, instead of copying a Doxygen-generated file there? Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I think this will work (never tried it and not sure about Windows), only when copying results to another place one has not to forget to take the files as well. A small culprit might also be that when updating the sources and not yet the documentation they might be out of sync.

Comment: No, that's not the idea. The links go from the bogus path generated by Doxygen to the correct html file generated by Doxygen. So there are never external files involved (i.e., sources in the original source tree), neither to copy nor to sync. But I'm struggling to have Doxygen invoke my command after it has generated the html. I want users to be able to run `doxygen Doxyfile` and get the complete html. Of course I can write a separate wrapper script, but an unwitting user may run `doxygen Doxyfile` anyway and then wonder about the broken links.

Comment: There is no post-processing possibility in doxygen, When necessary I always use a script / Makefile. Regarding `doxygen Doxyfile` I created a doxygen.bat (Windows) that does some things and calls the real doxygen.exe and could do some post-processing but the later will influence of course all doxygen runs). Something similar is possible on *nix systems (probably even with an alias).

Comment: The soft links don't work, and neither does a plain `cp` of the html file, because Doxygen uses relative paths in the html files and the bogus path has a different depth than the correctly placed html file. So I'm patching the html files instead, and this approach does work on my machine and should be portable among *nix, I think. It would be much nicer if Doxygen would just give me a callback to override link generation (along with generation of every other document component, ideally)... but whatever.

Comment: Indeed hen copying doxygen html files to another place (as well) will /can lead to some path problems. Maybe best to issue an enhancement request and describing (including small example) what you would like to have.